# Mounting folders with KubernetesPodOperator on Google Composer/Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to mount dags folder to be able to run a python script inside of the KubernetesPodOperator on Aiflow, but can't figure out how to do it. In production I would like to do it in Google Composer. Here is my task:

```
kubernetes_min_pod = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='pod-ex-minimum',
    cmds=["bash", "-c"],
    arguments=["cd /usr/local/tmp"],
    namespace='default',
    image='toru2220/scrapy-chrome:latest',
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    get_logs=True,
    in_cluster=False,
    volumes=[
        Volume("my-volume", {"persistentVolumeClaim": {"claimName": "my-volume"}})
    ],
    volume_mounts=[
        VolumeMount("my-volume", "/usr/local/tmp", sub_path=None, read_only=False)
    ],
)
```

I am trying to understand what is the easiest way to mount the current folder where dag is?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find out how to solve it?

Comment: Any thoughts on how we can mount Cloud Composer DAG Folder (which is a GCS Bucket) into the pod created via KubernetesPodOperator?

Answer (score 2):

As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/cloud-storage), when you create an environment, Cloud Composer creates a Cloud Storage bucket and associates the bucket with your environment. The name of the bucket is based on the environment region, name, and a random ID such as “us-central1-b1-6efannnn-bucket”. Cloud Composer stores the source code for your workflows (DAGs) and their dependencies in specific folders in Cloud Storage and uses [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to map the folders to the Airflow instances in your Cloud Composer environment.

The Cloud Composer runs on top of a GKE cluster with all the DAGs, tasks, and services running on a single node pool. As per your requirement, you are trying to mount a DAGs folder in your code, which is already mounted in the Airflow pods under “**/home/airflow/gcs/dags**” path. Please refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#begin) for more information about KubernetesPodOperator in Cloud Composer.