# How to mount folder/file to KubernetesPodOperator Airflow

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I need to run a python script from a KubernetesPodOperator, so I want to mount the python file into the Python docker Image. Reading some posts

- [How to mount volume of airflow worker to airflow kubernetes pod operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754521/how-to-mount-volume-of-airflow-worker-to-airflow-kubernetes-pod-operator)
- [Mounting volume issue through KubernetesPodOperator in GKE airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950206/mounting-volume-issue-through-kubernetespodoperator-in-gke-airflow)
- [Mounting folders with KubernetesPodOperator on Google Composer/Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539197/mounting-folders-with-kubernetespodoperator-on-google-composer-airflow)
- https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/example_dags/example_kubernetes.py#L107
- https://www.aylakhan.tech/?p=655

it doesn't get clear at all for me.

The python file is located in the route `/opt/airflow/dags/test_dag`, so I would like to mount the entire folder and not only the script. I have tried with:

```
    vol1 = k8s.V1VolumeMount(
        name='test_volume', mount_path='/opt/airflow/dags/test_dag'
    )
    volume = k8s.V1Volume(
        name='test-volume',
        persistent_volume_claim=k8s.V1PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource(claim_name='test-volume'),
    )

    k = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="dry_run_demo",
        cluster_name="eks",
        namespace="data",
        image="python:3.9-buster",
        volumes=[volume],
        volume_mounts=[vol1],
        arguments=["echo", "10"],
    )
```

But I am getting the error:

> Pod "pod.388baaaa7c27489c9dd5f7f37ee8ce5b" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "test_volume\

I am using Airflow 2.1.1 deployed in a EC2 with docker-compose and `apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==3.0.1`

EDIT: with Elad's suggestion the question was "solved". Then I got the error `Pod Event: FailedScheduling - persistentvolumeclaim "test-volume" not found`, so I just took out the `persistent_volume_claim` argument and I didn't get any error, but I am getting an empty directory in the POD, without any file. I have read something about creating the persistentvolumeclain in the namespace, but it would be very convenient to create it manually instead of dynamically with every operator

Comment: The names don't match you have `test_volume` and `test-volume`. Names should be the same

Comment: Hi Javier Lopez Tomas, does Elad's suggested volume name fix solve your problem?

Comment: Elad's suggestion solves the question with the original code, yes. But my problem is still going on because I am getting just an empty directory in the POD and no files at all

Comment: What version of k8s are you using? What is the output of  ´kubectl get pv,pvc -n data´ command?

Comment: @JavierLopezTomas did you able to solve the error (that came after fixing the claim name)? I am facing the issue of volume not found, is there anything you have done to fix the issue?

Comment: @vikas0713 I wasn't able. I kept facing errors and eventually I just changed the approach for building a docker image previous to the operator for having the files in the pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the names don't match.
you defined `name='test_volume'` for `V1VolumeMount` and `name='test-volume` for `V1Volume`.

To solve your issue names should be identical.

```
vol1 = k8s.V1VolumeMount(
    name='test-volume', mount_path='/opt/airflow/dags/test_dag'
)
volume = k8s.V1Volume(
    name='test-volume',
    persistent_volume_claim=k8s.V1PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource(claim_name='test-volume'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question with ongoing errors

Comment: @JavierLopezTomas claim_name references the user's PVC in the same namespace. This volume finds the bound PV and mounts that volume for the pod.